# Syntax error on line 21 of /httpd-autoindex.conf

Tags: apache

When I test the apache:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

I get the following error:

```
AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00526: Syntax error on line 21 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf:
Invalid command 'Alias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I then check the "httpd-autoindex.conf" file and not sure how it should be fixed

```
21    Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"
22
23    <Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">
24    Options Indexes MultiViews
25    AllowOverride None
26    Require all granted
27    </Directory>
```

Comment: please add line numbers

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you do not have the `alias` module enabled. I do not have a redhat based system on hand at the moment, so I do not know what folder exactly you can find it in, but on my Ubuntu system I have a folder called mods-enabled that contains `alias.load` and `alias.conf`.

Comment: I tried searching the forums to enable what you had mentioned but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: You can use `apachectl -M` to list modules. If alias is not listed then that could very well be the problem. That could at least help you figure out the cause.